# TypeError: connection.once(...).catch is not a function

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, error-handling, try-catch

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
function connectDB() {
    // Database connection 
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL, 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify : true });
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log('Database connected ');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Connection failed ');
    });`
```

}
everytime i am getting the error that catch is not a function at connectDB error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\mern\config\db.js:15
    }).catch(err => {
            ^

TypeError: connection.once(...).catch is not a function
    at connectDB (C:\Users\user\Desktop\mern\config\db.js:15:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.on` after `.once`

https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/mongoose/Connection/once

```
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', function () {
      console.log('MongoDB running');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```